# cannot send mail through action mailer in catarse app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I am developing an app using catarse platform where i want to send an email to users asking them to be a part of a project team. 
I am using action mailer.In my rails console i could see that message is sent successfully but it does not get delivered to inbox or span folder of the recipient.
Here is my development.rb

```
Catarse::Application.configure do
  Slim::Engine.set_default_options pretty: true
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true

  # mailcatcher configs

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :enable_starttls_auto => true,
    :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :port => 587,
    :domain => "gmail.com",
    :authentication => :login,
    :user_name => *******,
    :password => *******,
  }

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can u send snapshot of mailer file where u have defined function to send mail,

actually i wanted to look whether u have defined

`default_from: test123@example.com`

in the mailer or not, as u had said that it is showing on rails server...
so this may b the case.

u can define default_from in your mailer file or in development.rb/production.rb

as `ActionMailer::Base.default :from => 'test123@example.com'`

Comment: @vape now i think its sufficient for author to understand

Answer (score 0):

looks like i figured it out i was missing 
default from: "xxxxx@xxx.xxx"
in my user_mailer.rb

Comment: Please explain why this worked so that future visitors to your question will understand.

Comment: its compulsory to specify the address of the sender in your mailer.rb file or else the email will not be sent.Thanks War10ck i will remember to explain my answers in future so i can be of some good to somebody.